# Will BCryptPasswordEncoder automatically encode the default password created by Spring Security?

Tags: spring-boot, spring-security, bcrypt, restful-authentication

I'm learning about Spring Security and I created a simple RestController with a method to retrieve data from the database.

After that I added Spring Security dependency in the pom.xml. And Spring created a username and password for me. And now I need to use this username and password if I want to retrieve the data from the database.

After that I want to add the BCryptPasswordEncoder and I just add this code in the SpringBootApplication main class:

```
@Bean
public BCryptPasswordEncoder bCryptPasswordEncoder() {
    return new BCryptPasswordEncoder();
}
```

And now if I try to login with the username and password created by Spring it's not working. I want to know if just adding this code will encode the default password created by Spring behind the scene? And why when I try to login with this password Spring doesn't encode my password again? What code should I add to encode the password when I login? Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

Without knowing what version of Spring Security you are using, I will answer with that you will do in Spring Security 5

```java
@Bean
public PasswordEncoder passwordEncoder() {
    return PasswordEncoderFactories.createDelegatingPasswordEncoder();
}

@Bean
public UserDetailsService userDetailsService() {
    return new InMemoryUserDetailsManager(
        User.builder()
            .passwordEncoder(input -> passwordEncoder().encode(input))
            .username("user")
            .password("{bcrypt}$2a$10$dXJ3SW6G7P50lGmMkkmwe.20cQQubK3.HZWzG3YB1tlRy.fqvM/BG")
            .roles("USER")
            .build()
    );
}
```

The delegating password encoder supports many different password formats and will auto detect it based on the `{bcrypt}` prefix.

The integration test can look like this

```java
@SpyBean
public UserDetailsService userDetailsService;

private User.UserBuilder user = User.withDefaultPasswordEncoder()
    .username("user")
    .password("password")
    .roles("USER");

@Test
@DisplayName("form login works")
void happyPath() throws Exception {
    doReturn(user.build())
        .when(userDetailsService).loadUserByUsername(any(String.class));
    mvc.perform(
        MockMvcRequestBuilders.post("/login")
            .param("username", "user")
            .param("password", "password")
    )
        .andExpect(status().is3xxRedirection())
        .andExpect(redirectedUrl("/"))
        .andExpect(authenticated())
    ;
}
```

as you can see, the server stores the password in bcrypt format. The client sends it in clear text (`.param("password", "password")`)

I used a spybean so that I can modify what the UserDetailsService returns. Since it has a habit of caching things.

The sample project is available [online](https://github.com/fhanik/spring-security-community/blob/e67649e5328e2dff90a1f75d382dd361cf1b4597/samples/bearer-token-filter-chain/src/test/java/org/springframework/security/community/samples/SpyOnTheFailureHandlerTests.java?ts=4#L40-L41)